# How to get time when Firebase Scheduled Cloud Function executes?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks

I have tasks stored in firestore with timestamp, task data and one boolean field called active which is false by default.

Let's say that i have 2 tasks, one with timestamp 11:15 and one with timestamp 11:45. My scheduled cloud function runs every 15min and checks if there is a task in firestore in that time. If there is a task it sets active field to true.

I have i cloud function which runs on every 15min and it looks like this.

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('*/15 * * * *').onRun((context) => {

    return null;
  });
```

I have several questions.

- How to get time when scheduled function is meant to be executed? If, let's say, that time is 10:30 i want to have reference to that time in my code so i can check with values in firestore.
- How to query through firestore and check if there is timestamp with same value as scheduled function?

I'm new to cloud functions so any advice or code snippet would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get time when scheduled function is meant to be executed? If,
> let's say, that time is 10:30 i want to have reference to that time in
> my code so i can check with values in firestore.

You should use the [`timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext#timestamp) property of the `context` object, as follows:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('*/15 * * * *').onRun((context) => {

    const executionTimestamp = context.timestamp; // The timestamp at which the event happened.

    return null;
  });
```

> How to query through Firestore and check if there is timestamp with
> same value as scheduled function?

It depends how you store the Timestamp in your Firestore database. If you use a standard [Firestore Date type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types?authuser=0), you can use a Firestore [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) Object in your query, as follows:

```
  admin      // Using the Admin SDK since this code is to be used in a Cloud Function
    .firestore()
    .collection('collection')
    .where('timestampField', '==', admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(...)))
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          // ....
      });
    });
```

Note that you can very well use the `>`, `<=`, `>=` and `>` operators in your query.

Comment: According to my tests, `context.timestamp` is not the scheduled time but when the function actually started.

Comment: @gustavopch have you got to know how to get the scheduled time.

Comment: @AkshayMasram Unfortunately not